# Can't Boot from USB Flash Drive & my BIOS is unlike any other

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

I believe I'm doing everything correctly, but I must be missing something. I have a Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 8gb flash drive formatted in FAT32 to boot Kali Linux (with Linux Live USB Creator). I plug the flash drive into my computer while it's on (with Windows 7) and it senses the flash drive, but when I reboot and go into my boot settings there's no option to boot from my flash drive. I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 7520 with a very lightweight version of Windows Ultimate (without extra drivers or software) installed on it. Since I installed that I've got most of my old drivers back but there's still some missing things I don't know how to reinstall, and I think that may have to do with this issue. For example, I could mount an ISO image to my drive before I replaced Windows 7 Professional with Windows 7 Ultimate.

Since I don't have enough reputation points; here's a link to several images of me searching through menu's and sub-menu's for a USB boot option (the last picture's of my boot settings/menu, which is separate from my BIOS): https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5vRP.jpg

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you boot from Hard Drive, does windows boot or can you select
  HDD's (in one of my bios'es I get USB devices listed there).
- What Options do you have for "Boot List Option"? I don't know about Kali Linux but most likely you have to change this to "legacy" or any other option that is not meaning uefi.
- What options do you have for "Change boot mode setting"? Try switchting it to other option not meaning uefi.

If you can't get it to work this way, try creating the USB stick again with Rufus (https://rufus.akeo.ie/). I was struggling getting a win7 uefi install stick but this tool helped me. Set it to

- GPT
- FAT32 Format
- Pick your iso (Kali Linux in your case) - Important: Recheck above made settings since they can change.

EDIT: if this doesnt help, check the first answer here: [ifixit link](https://de.ifixit.com/Answers/View/110162/Add+Boot+Option+using+Insydeh20+setup+utility) or google for insydeh20 bios usb boot.

Comment: The problem is not the flash drive itself, as I can boot from it on another computer. Also, switching my boot mode to legacy mode nearly trashed my boot sector last time.

Comment: Have you seen my edit (ifixit link)? Else I'm sorry I couldn't help, this BIOS seems like a real struggle.

Comment: I am sorry. You were right. Apparently my Kali ISO was missing two dll files. Rufus detected that Linux Live USB Creator did not.